# how to use input-group-btn in materialize css framework

Tags: materialize

I want to put + and - buttons inside input box but bootstraps input-group-btn property is not working in materialize CSS framework

[image: Screenshot]

```
<div class="row marg">
    <h6 class="small">Selling Quantity</h6>
    <div class="input-field input-group col s12">
        <span class="suffix btn-number" data-type="minus" data-field="num">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light ">
                <i class="material-icons grey-text text-darken-1 left">remove</i>
            </a>
        </span>

        <input type="text" name="num" class="form-control input-number"  value="">

        <span class="suffix btn-number"  data-type="plus" data-field="num">
            <a class=" waves-effect waves-light "><i class="material-icons grey-text text-darken-1 left">add</i></a>
        </span>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines.

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

There is no class like "input-group" in Materialize.

> Bootstrap and Materialize differ in class names.

Check their Forms.html - http://materializecss.com/forms.html

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col s12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s6">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
      <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_telephone">Telephone</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```